# How to parse multiple tags with their classes in beautifulsoup in python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML with multiple
`<div class="parent">parent text</div>`

and its child`<div class="random symbols">child text</div><i class="child"></i>`

For example:

`<div class="parent">parent text<div class="random symbols">child text</div><i class="child"></i></div>`

And I want to parse it with BeautifulSoup, such that I get at the end:

```
parent text
child text
parent text
child text
parent text
child text
...
```

How to do it? I tried parsing only tag `i`, then moving to its `previous_sibling()` and getting by their `next_element` the result is:

```
child text
child text
child text
```

But I want to combine them.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure what the finally result that u want,so I only could give u some idea may help u.

Divide and conquer

Find all the parent,parsing once at time to get the result that you want,such as `parent text`,`child text`

Here is some code u may could try to use,just see the `contents` parsing the target that u want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text= """
<div class="parent">
    parent text
    <div class="random symbols">child text</div>
    <i class="child"></i>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

es = soup.find_all(class_='parent')
for e in es:
    print(e.contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have mentioned that there are multiple `div` tags, I have considered two `div`s in my example.*

Find all the `div` with class `parent` and then we can extract the parent text and child text.

```py
import bs4 as bs
h = '<div class="parent">parent text<div class="random symbols">child text</div><i class="child"></i></div><div class="parent">parent text<div class="random symbols">child text</div><i class="child"></i></div>'

soup = bs.BeatifulSoup(h, 'lxml')
t = soup.findAll('div', class_='parent')

for i in t:
    temp = i.contents
    print(temp[0], temp[1].text, sep="\n")
```